# Is it possible to run more than one training models in the same time in azure ml?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to run more than one training models in the same time in            Azure ML?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can train multiple modules concurrently in a single experiment in Azure ML. (More generally, you can have [up to four modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-faq) running at a time in an Azure ML Studio experiment.) If you have a standard (paid) workspace, you can also have multiple experiments running at the same time, so in principle, you could be training even more than four models at the same time.

You can also use multiple trained models for scoring in a single predictive experiment. (Just drag them in from the Trained Models section of the modules list.)